# Prevent View Controller from extending under status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios-statusbar

I have a view controller which is the rootVc for Navigation Controller.

I needed the navigation bar to be hiddden for the rootview controller hence I used the following method to hide it and make it reappear.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}

 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

I'm basically hiding the navigation bar in the rootVc and showing it for all other view controllers.

But when I remove the NavBar I see that my content is extending under the status bar

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: check for safe area in your code or UIStoryboard.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS  the safe area is extending to the top of the view controller.

Comment: I think that code does exactly what you wrote. It seems that you may need to update constraints programmatically as you remove the bar from code

Comment: @Болат-Тлеубаев so do I need to add a margin after removing the nav bar ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the top constraint to superView use **safe area**.
Something like this

[image]